# How to use a file based repository in sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt, artifact

In sbt, I want to publish a project's artifacts to a local folder and then use those artifacts in another project.

In project A, I can publish the artifacts using this:

```
publishTo := Some(Resolver.file("file",  new File( Path.userHome.absolutePath + "/myMavenRepo/releases" )) )
```

followed by `sbt publish`. I am able to see the .jar file and other artifacts in the `myMavenRepo/releases/` folder.

However, when I add this to project B:

```
Resolver.file("myRepo", file(Path.userHome.absolutePath + "/myMavenRepo/releases")) transactional()
```

... then the project A dependency is not resolved.

*Am I using these APIs incorrectly?*

By the way, I don't want to use `publishLocal` because these are experimental projects and don't want them to pollute the repository under `~/.sbt/` folder.